# How to resolve the issue of Curl request while they are working sometimes but sometimes not?

Tags: curl

I am trying to send a request to another server to complete some actions using CURL. Problem is that it is working most of the time but sometimes request is not passing on the other side. I am sure on this as I have checked this by putting Logs on both side...System makes log entry everytime at My Side but it seems that request is not passing other side as there is no log entry found in case when action does not complete.

Please suggest something here as I could not get the issue why request is not passing sometimes.

Comment: Is this question related to programming at all? I can't tell.

Comment: Curl requests are related to programming...In my case, I think programming wise mostly it works perfectly but sometimes it doesn't work. Might be there is some server related issue but I can't say about that as I don't have much knowledge about that.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I have figured it out as system was getting same request from the other section of module and processing that.